# R Plotting three timeseries in two facet_grids in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid

Is it possible to plot three timeseries in only two grids using ggplot and `facet_grid()`?

```
# Create some fake data
stock1 = cumprod(1+c(0, rnorm(99, 0, .05)))
stock2 = cumprod(1+c(0, rnorm(99, 0, .075)))
indicator = sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
date_seq = seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1)

df = data.frame(date = date_seq, stock1 = stock1, stock2 = stock2, indicator = indicator)
```

Now I would like to see an upper graph with the two stocks and one lower graph with the indicator using facet_grid().

The only result I get is a three-grid plot

```
grid_df = pivot_longer(df, c(stock1, stock2, indicator), names_to = "underlying", values_to = "values")

ggplot(grid_df, aes(x = date, y = values, colour = underlying)) +
     geom_line() +
     facet_grid(vars(underlying), scales = "free")
```

I dont know how to group the two stocks to bring them into one grid.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra column to your longer format data where you could combine the stocks 1 and 2 to one string called stocks and leave the indicator alone using an `ifelse` to assign them to the `facet_grid` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
grid_df = pivot_longer(df, c(stock1, stock2, indicator), names_to = "underlying", values_to = "values") %>%
  mutate(grids = ifelse(underlying == "indicator", "indicator", "stock"))

ggplot(grid_df, aes(x = date, y = values, colour = underlying)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(vars(grids), scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>